# Docker Laravel migration error Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I have this error when running php artisan migrate:fresh:

```
#15 0.576    Illuminate\Database\QueryException 
#15 0.576   SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: laravel8-php-fpm-80
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    networks:
      - app-network

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.33
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: db
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - app-network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.8-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 8100:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - app-network
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.0.3-fpm-buster

RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath pdo_mysql

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git zip unzip
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY . /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www
RUN composer install
RUN php artisan config:clear
RUN php artisan migrate:fresh

EXPOSE 9000
```

My env file:

```
APP_NAME=App Name
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:1XGhFF8+2qNi2IPyQVgdv783pZqTgsUl4Y77K9gUoYY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

in my config/database.php I got:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'forge'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

I'm new in docker, so maybe I'm missing something. Does anyone know what may be the problem here :( I spent two days investigating this error and didn't find any good answer

Comment: I think you did not run the migrations, not sure why because you have it in your `Dockerfile` (I would recommend to do not do that sort of stuff on that file, do it manually once the container is up, same for composer and any other command...)

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution by running bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Migration Started";
 php artisan migrate
 echo "Seeding started"
 php artisan db:seed
 echo "Server starting"
return
```

but now I have problem because my migrations are running in loop, migrating never stops. I don't know why it behaves like this. Does anyone know a solution to this migration in loop problem? I also tried with adding php artisan serve before return statement and migrations finished and server does start, but then my problem is I cannot open application on port 8100, I think its because of artisan serve.